# Why can't I get data from the server to the client?

Tags: c#, networking, server, udp, client

I send to the server the text from the console and the server sends it to me.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ipserv = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("46.174.49.48"), 46666);
        client.Connect(ipserv);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
        client.Send(data);
        client.Receive(data); //here is the error
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Error: The remote host forcibly broke the existing connection

Server working

Comment: You need to post code that can reproduce the problem.  You'll need to either supply code for the server or alternatively if the server belongs to a 3rd party, supply some details of the server you're attempting to communicate with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a try-catch statement in order to understand better. It is hapenning for one or more of these reasons:
1) You are sending malformed data to the application or (2)The network link between the client and server is going down for some reason...... (3)You have triggered a bug in the third-party application that caused it to crash (4)The third-party application has exhausted system resources It's likely that the first I would say that is the number 1.

Example:::

```
try {  
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);  

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.  
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");  

            // Send the data through the socket.  
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);  

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);  
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",  
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));  

            // Release the socket.  
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            sender.Close();  

        } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {  
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}",ane.ToString());  
        } catch (SocketException se) {  
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.ToString());  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());  
        }  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());  
    }
```